# handling atom of probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If X is a non-negative random variable with an atom at zero, then for $u=0$ does $\int_{0}^{u}\mathbb{P}(X>t)dt$ equal to zero or the probability mass at zero?

Comment: Once atoms are present in your distribution, you need to start thinking in terms of either Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals (with respect to the cumulative distribution function) or Lebesgue integrals with respect to the associated probability measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Zero.

To begin with, $P(X\gt t)$ is always between $0$ and $1$ hence the integral from $0$ to $u$ is between $0$ and $u$, QED.